# How to catch SIGBUS error?

Tags: c++, linux, signals

I am trying to catch the error on read only memory but unable to do it?
If i handle the error then it program  can continue or only option is exit/abort?

```js
#include<iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
char * F00()
{
        char *s2="ab";
        return s2;
}

void InvalidMem()
{
                (F00())[0]='l';
}



void
termination_handler (int signum)
{
        fprintf(stderr,"BUS error");
}

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        signal (SIGBUS, termination_handler);

        InvalidMem();

        for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
                std::cout<<" L " ;

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Continue from what point?

Comment: Attempting to continue from such a serious crash *is* possible, but how would you know that the program is in such a state that it can safely continue? In short: You can't. Instead of trying to "catch" the crash and attempting to continue, you should find the root cause of the crash and fix that problem instead of just try to ignore it.

Comment: Joachim, I agree with you about the state but does it mean if I catch a signal then program can continue from the point which cause the raise of signal.

Comment: If I am adding the following:
signal (SIGSEGV, termination_handler);
Then it caught in infinite loop and always printing BUS error.

Comment: Like I said, it is *possible*, but ***never*** a good idea!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SIGBUS means you are accessing an unaligned address, SIGSEGV means you are accessing an address you are "not supposed to" (either invalid address, or writing to read-only memory - in some cases memory can be write-only, and a read from such memory would then result in SIGSEGV too).

Since the processor doesn't really know how what state it is in when you end up in the signal handler, it is typically not possible to just continue from the signal handler itself in these cases. Instead, the typical approach is to use `setjmp` and `longjmp` to "recover to a known point". This may be the "main loop" of your code, or some error recovery point.

So, something like this:

```
 jmp_buf reset;

 int termination_handler(int signum)
 {
     longjmp(reset, 1);
 }

 int main()
 {
    if (setjmp(reset) != 0)
    {
        printf("We got back from signal handler")
        ...
    }
    signal (SIGBUS, termination_handler);
    ...
    return 0;
 }
```

It should be noted that you can get into some serious trouble if you actually "keep going" after execution errors like bus fault or address fault - consider for example:

```
// At global level:
  some_lock lock;

// in some function. 
  ....
  lock->take();
  some code that crashes;
  lock->release();
```

So, now the lock is held, and never released... Code will probably hang next time you need to take the lock...

Comment: I agree with you but I want to know all the possibilities here.

Comment: "All the possibilities" is quite a wide range, and in all OS's that I'm aware of, just returning from a signal handler when the previous operaiton was invalid, the OS will terminate the process. So you need to "get out of the signal handler, without returning" - it's a bit like in monopoly, "Go straight to jail, do not pass go".